# The plus operator is not accepting raw string operands

Tags: c++

I get an error when trying to print concatenated strings:

```
std::cout << "some string" + "another string";
```

I get this error:

```
Operator does not take these operands.
```

I thought `"some string"` was a `std::string` literal.  What is going on?

Comment: Where are those "std string operands" you mention in the question title?

Comment: i think we are giving OP too hard a time. If a new C++ programmer is raised to always use std::string (hooray!) then in fact "xxxx" is a std::string in their mind (they have never seen char *). And now they are confused when the string aaa and string "bbb" dont behave the same

Comment: @pm100" It is a universally respected pedagogical technique known as "tough love". We are using it deliberately and thoughtfully .

Comment: Not enough rep to edit title.  You guys are cutthroat,  this is a bad place to ask questions if you don't already know the mf answer aparently:-/

Comment: @saramalone - Depends on what kind of programming questions you ask.   I usually answer under MATLAB, and most of us are pretty friendly.  The people you encounter here are not a full representation of the StackOverflow community so if they do bother you, don't let them.  You're here to get an answer and you have certainly showed us what you tried, which is more than what I've seen in most posts here.

Comment: Sometimes people don't know enough to ask the question properly... I'm amazed that some people forget this (especially those with 150k+ rep).

Answer (score 3):

Binary `+` is not supposed to take these operands. C++ language does not have such `+` operator and never had one. You cannot add two string literals to each other.

Why you mention `std::string` in the question title is not clear to me. There's no `std::string` in your example. String literals are not `std::string` objects. String literals are just arrays of `const char`. They have no relation to `std::string` and they will not be magically converted to `std::string` for you.

If you want to use `std::string` in this case you have to convert at least one of your literals to `std:string` explicitly

```
cout << std::string("some string") + "another string";
```

In the case the overload resolution rules will make the compiler to consider the binary `+` operator for `std::string` objects and convert the second operand to `std::string` implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Those are not `std::string`-operands, where `+` really concatenates, but *string literals*.

String literals represent arrays of constant characters (including an implicit 0-terminator), which are not addable (`const char[]`). Neither are the pointers they decay to.

Still, concatenating them is really easy: Just leave out anything between them but whitespace, and the compiler will do it for you.

As an aside, [since C++14 one *can* actually write `std::string`-literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s):

```
#include <string>
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
// the last two are inline-namespace, could leave them off to get more.

...

"std::string-literal"s // Note the `s` behind the string-literal.
```

Comment: Note that saying that a string literal is not a string is confusing. Experienced c++ coders understand that string != string in that case but newcomers do not

Comment: i was commenting on this answer more on the fact that the word string is used very lightly in c++ even though it has very strong meanings. The OP was obviously confused by this

Comment: `[*]` might be confusing at this level of question.

Answer (score 1):

To create a `std::string` literal, you have to do the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  using namespace std::string_literals;
  std::cout << "some string"s + "another string"s; 
}
```

notice the trailing `s`.

The sequence `"some string"` is not a `std::string` literal, but rather a `const char[12]` buffer of raw characters.  This comes from C, where there was no `std::string`.  In addition, it means that if you prefer a different string library, `std::string` has no built-in advantage.

With you post-fix with that `s` (after bringing the literals into view), you get a `std::string` literal.

This is a C++14 feature.  In C++03 you can get a similar effect by doing

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << std::string("some string") + std::string("another string");
}
```

Comment: You forgot `#include <iostream>`